# Android Left to Right slide animation with swipe

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I am developing an android application and i have set of messages to show on a display page. and only one message will be shown at a time, but if user swipes the screen i want to change the message on textview on swipe in animated fashion. I want animation direction based on swipe direction meaning if user swipe left to right then left-right textview animation, similarly right-left and bottom-top animation. Please advise me how to achieve this.

Comment: for swiping use viewpager...

Comment: Put some dummy text-views in your view.Then,in your onTouch method, change the position of the touched the textview according to the position of the fingers.